# create object from DB table

Tags: php, oop

sample DB:

```
level1  | level2      | level3 | datatype | maxlen | minlen
-----------------------------------------------------------
version | NULL        | NULL   | element  | 0      | 0
version | release     | NULL   | string   | 2      | 0  
version | build       | NULL   | string   | 5      | 0
service | NULL        | NULL   | element  | 0      | 0
service | subservice1 | NULL   | element  | 0      | 0
service | subservice1 | value1 | string   | 10     | 5
service | subservice1 | value2 | string   | 50     | 1
```

This table (I omitted a bunch in this sample) represents default values (string lengths, required/optional flags and other things) for a SOAP API.
I've tried several approaches but none took me where I wanted to go. I guess I don't quite grasp the concept of recursiveness (is that a word?).

What I need is an object

```
stdClass Object (
    [version] => stdClass Object (
        [release] => stdClass Object (
            [maxlen] => 2
            [minlen] => 0
        )
        [build] => stdClass Object (
            [maxlen] => 5
            [minlen] => 0
        )       
    )
    [service] => stdClass Object (
        [subservice1] => stdClass Object (
            [value1] => stdClass Object (
                [maxlen] => 10
                [minlen] => 5
            )
            [value2] => stdClass Object (
                [maxlen] => 50
                [minlen] => 1
            )
        )
    )
)
```

and so on. There are up to 7 Levels and I want to be able to access default values like this

```
$var = $object->service->subservice1->value1->maxlen
```

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: So the first table is the db contents that you'd like to create an object from? With a fixed number of levels? In that case I'd go easy on myself and write some ifs. Like "if($row['level3']) <create 3rd level object> else if ($row['level2']) ..."

Comment: You can take a look at Doctrine http://doctrine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/manual/introduction.html

This is a platform to get object from a database. 

On the other side, you can create your own object bij creating classes for them and put the info in the fields that you define, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: `grasp the concept` dont worry about that, try an implementation and if you get stuck maybe SO can help you then.

Comment: This is actually the API of DHL and so far I have only looked at ShipmentOrder which allows you to create a shipment. I think there could be more levels when I'm implementing more and other services, and also I've already seen changes from the last version of the API to the recent one. As far as I remember, there were only 6 levels a while ago... I've tried the if/else approach but somehow kept getting warnings `Attempt to assign property of non-object`.. until I pulled my hair out...

Comment: thanx for the hints, I will check them out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$root = (object) [];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['datatype'] == 'Element') {
        continue;
    }

    $tgt = &$root;
    for($i = 1; $i <= 7; ++$i) {
        $rowkey = 'L'.$i;

        if ($row[$rowkey] === null) {
            break;
        }

        if (!property_exists($tgt, $row[$rowkey])) {
            $tgt->{$row[$rowkey]} = (object) [];
        }

        $tgt = &$tgt->{$row[$rowkey]};
    }

    $tgt = (object) [
        'minLength' => $row['minLength'],
        'maxLength' => $row['maxLength'],
        'required'  => $row['required'],
        'note'      => $row['note'],
        'value'     => ''
    ];
}
unset($tgt);
```

Note: I haven't run it as I didn't have any test data. Should be fairly close to working though.

As others have already said: Spend some time reading about objects, etc, in order to *understand* what you're using.

*Very* fundamental rule of coding: [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) I'm impressed that you didn't tire of typing all those ->$L halfway through it ;).

Also, please note the &. Be careful when using that([PHP references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php))

(And please let me know in case the code doesn't work with your data :))

Comment: Thank you so much. And apologies for not getting back to you sooner. Works great!! I had to add a missing $ (tried to edit here too, hope it worked). You're right, I always try to not repeat myself. For some reason I just couldn't wrap my head around this... and I hated my code anyway. `&$ref` is a new concept for me, I'll have to look this up. So thanks again for your efforts. Everything seems to work and I will build from here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it at all, but it seems to work...

```
CLASS dhl_object {

        public $objTemplate;


        public function __construct() {

            global $conn_secuser;

            if(!$result = getAllRows($conn_secuser, "reference_dhl")) {
                return FALSE;
            } else {

                if($result->num_rows<=0) {
                    return FALSE;
                } else {

                    $object = new stdClass();

                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                        $id     =   $row["id"];
                        $L1     =   $row["L1"];
                        $L2     =   $row["L2"];
                        $L3     =   $row["L3"];
                        $L4     =   $row["L4"];
                        $L5     =   $row["L5"];
                        $L6     =   $row["L6"];
                        $L7     =   $row["L7"];
                        $dataType   =   $row["dataType"];
                        $minLength  =   $row["minLength"];
                        $maxLength  =   $row["maxLength"];
                        $required   =   $row["required"];
                        $note       =   $row["note"];

                        // possible dataTypes: Element, String, Decimal, Integer, Enumeration
                        if($dataType!="Element") {

                            if($L7) {

                                if(!isset($object->$L1)) $object->$L1 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2)) $object->$L1->$L2 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6->$L7)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6->$L7 = new stdClass();

                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6->$L7->minLength   = $minLength;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6->$L7->maxLength   = $maxLength;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6->$L7->required    = $required;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6->$L7->note        = $note;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6->$L7->value       = "";

                            } else
                            if($L6) {

                                if(!isset($object->$L1)) $object->$L1 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2)) $object->$L1->$L2 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6 = new stdClass();

                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6->minLength    = $minLength;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6->maxLength    = $maxLength;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6->required     = $required;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6->note         = $note;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->$L6->value        = "";

                            } else
                            if($L5) {

                                if(!isset($object->$L1)) $object->$L1 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2)) $object->$L1->$L2 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5 = new stdClass();

                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->minLength = $minLength;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->maxLength = $maxLength;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->required  = $required;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->note      = $note;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->$L5->value     = "";

                            } else
                            if($L4) {

                                if(!isset($object->$L1)) $object->$L1 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2)) $object->$L1->$L2 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4 = new stdClass();

                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->minLength  = $minLength;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->maxLength  = $maxLength;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->required   = $required;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->note       = $note;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->$L4->value      = "";

                            } else
                            if($L3) {

                                if(!isset($object->$L1)) $object->$L1 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2)) $object->$L1->$L2 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2->$L3)) $object->$L1->$L2->$L3 = new stdClass();

                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->minLength   = $minLength;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->maxLength   = $maxLength;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->required    = $required;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->note        = $note;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->$L3->value       = "";

                            } else
                            if($L2) {

                                if(!isset($object->$L1)) $object->$L1 = new stdClass();
                                if(!isset($object->$L1->$L2)) $object->$L1->$L2 = new stdClass();

                                $object->$L1->$L2->minLength    = $minLength;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->maxLength    = $maxLength;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->required     = $required;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->note         = $note;
                                $object->$L1->$L2->value        = "";

                            } else
                            if($L1) {

                                if(!isset($object->$L1)) $object->$L1 = new stdClass();

                                $object->$L1->minLength = $minLength;
                                $object->$L1->maxLength = $maxLength;
                                $object->$L1->required  = $required;
                                $object->$L1->note      = $note;
                                $object->$L1->value     = "";

                            } 

                        }

                    }

                    $this->objTemplate = $object;

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

I'm hoping someone has a suggestion for improvement.. :)